# .min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, runtime-error, runtime

i'm trying to solve the threesumcloset problem on leetcode but i am getting a runtime error saying ".min() arg is an empty sequence". It's weird because the code runs perfectly in my text editor. Can anyone help me please?

```
def threeSumClosest(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        #take in the list
        input = [-1, 2, 1, -4]
        target = 1
        sum = 0

        #creates the list to compare to target
        sum_list = []
        abs_list = []


        #1st for loop 
        for first in nums:

            #2nd loop excluding 1st
            for second in nums:
                if nums.index(first) == nums.index(second):
                    #find a way to skip that number
                    continue
                else:
                    pass
                #3rd loop excluding 1st and 2nd and adds to list 
                for third in nums:
                    if nums.index(first) == nums.index(third) or nums.index(second) == nums.index(third):
                    #find a way to skip that number
                        continue
                    else:
                        pass
                    sum = first + second + third
                    sum_list.append(sum)

        #cast to set and print sum_list
        sum_list = set(sum_list)
        print(sum_list)
        #create a list with the abs of the diff btw the target and sum_list
        abs_list = list(map(lambda x: abs(x - target), sum_list) )
        final_index = abs_list.index(min(abs_list))
        sum_list = list(sum_list)
        return (sum_list[final_index])
```

Comment: `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence` will be raised when you pass an empty collection to the `min` function. This probably means there is a test case that results in `sum_list` being empty.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: What are the values of `sum_list` and `target` when the error occurs?

Comment: You really need to define the behavior of your code in case `abs_list` ends up empty. `min()` must always get a non-empty sequence, or an error like the one you encounter results.